# Javascript Calculator Function: How does it work?

Tags: javascript

I'm going through some tutorials and saw this block of code that I can't figure out. Can someone walk me through it please? I don't understand how the return ultimately executes the variable function.

```
var plus = function(x,y){ return x + y };
var minus = function(x,y){ return x - y };
var operations = {
  '+': plus,
  '-': minus
};

var calculate = function(x, y, operation){
    return operations[operation](x, y);
}

calculate(38, 4, '+');
calculate(47, 3, '-');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Look at my comments for an explanation.

```
var plus = function(x,y){ return x + y }; //-- var plus contains this function now.
var minus = function(x,y){ return x - y };
var operations = {
  '+': plus, //-- This states that '+' contains the plus function.
  '-': minus //-- This states that '-' contains the minus function.
};
var calculate = function(x, y, operation){ //-- operation makes it able to select a function from operations.
    return operations[operation](x, y);
}
calculate(38, 4, '+'); //-- The '+' selects the plus function here.
calculate(47, 3, '-'); //-- The '-' selects the minus function here.
```

Answer (score 3):

operations is an object that has + and - as keys, so by passing one of those to it you will get

```
operations['+'] = plus
```

Now, the brackets indicate a function call which can also be made via a variable as in this case. So translated the return statement is nothing more than

```
return plus(x,y);
```

---

```
var calculate = function(x, y, operation){

    return operations[operation](x, y); // operations['+'] = plus
}
```

Which calls above method and returns the value returned by that method.

Answer (score 2):

Executions will be something like this:

> First argument is being passed as a key of the object and respective function is executed with arguments..

```
var calculate=function(x, y, operation)
        {
            //operations['+'](38, 4);
            //operations['-'](47, 3);
            return operations[operation](x, y);
        };
```